# Mac OS X 10.6 : OpenSSL library

Tags: macos, unix, openssl

I have received an old code on the Mac and trying to compile it on OS X 10.6, in the code there are few calls to OpenSSL library (such as SSL_write()) I added the headers (#include ) in those files and check my version of OpenSSL shows me "0.9.8r" (I know Apple has it's own framework for this library crypto' ) but why I get the Link error as this:

```
  sockets::TcpSocket::TryWrite(char const*, unsigned long) in TcpSocket.o
```

I know the code should compile against this library in `/usr/lib` but it doesn't, do I missing path or other setting in Xcode?

Comment: `sockets::TcpSocket::TryWrite` is not OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

There are no libraries in /usr/bin. I assume you mean /usr/lib. You generally do not compile against /usr/lib, however. You usually compile against a specific SDK, which has its own copy of /usr/lib and /usr/include. The SDK header files you use is generally passed in the `-isysroot` parameter. If you're building in Xcode, these settings are set primarily via the "Base SDK" and "OS X Deployment Target." Without more specifics of how you're building, I'm not certain where else to point you, though. In particular, what does the compile and link lines look like for the relevant file?

---

In Xcode, don't try to link against specific system libraries by path. You should always link against system libraries using the Link Phase panel of the build settings, and selecting from the SDK list of libraries. Selecting specific paths in the Link Phase panel almost always leads to problems.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry I meant usr/lib. Regarding that missing library which I guess it would be openssl, I linked it against  SDKs/MacOSX10.6/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib, it would give me a set of other link errors such as :  "vtable for sockets::Exception", referenced from:

  sockets::Exception::~Exception()in EventHandler.o
  "sockets::SSLInitializer::SSLInitializer()", referenced from:
   __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in TcpSocket.o
  "_ERR_error_string", referenced from:
      sockets::TcpSocket::TryWrite(char const*, unsigned long)in TcpSocket.o